# Why cant we see fairies, nagas and garudas in Buddhism?

Tags: buddhist-cosmology

Do they exist in the same terrestrial world as ours, or is there a realm where they exist that is only accessible once you progress up the spiritual ladder?

Comment: I think they are here simulatenously with us and the higher beings exist as non-localized spirits of objects. Mind must become sharp to see them, or so have I heard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this one because this is a subject near to my heart.  The early days of my spiritual practice began like most disaffected Christian spiritual seekers in the west - I pursued paganism and Western occultism.  If you're asking this question, I don't need to tell you that these entities you mention do exist or, at least, we can have the experience of some unseen forces that defy conventional understanding.

The early 2000s hit, and like most people who came of age in that era, the New Atheist movement was becoming massively influential.  I turned to Zen Buddhism to slate my spiritual thirst in a way that didn't believe in all that fairy silliness.  I practiced diligently for over a decade until I had my first notable daikensho experience.  And guess what?  There were those blooming fairies asking what the hell took me so long!  The very act of ignoring the possibility of their existence was a barrier for me on the Buddhist path.  It was only after I allowed the possibility of their existence that the way opened for me in my Zen practice.  A practice that was once antiseptically sterile suddenly became an utter delight with angels hiding under every stone and yakshas calling from every tree.

But a word of caution is in order here.  You will meet these creatures in your practice.  In fact, some weird, fanciful, and paranormal experiences are a sign of progress.  But you know the koan about killing the Buddha on the street if you meet him?  Don't be hesitant to kill fairies either.  Seeking them out and obsessing over these encounters can sidetrack your progress.  They are just one dharma gate.  There are innumerable others.  Some are enchanting, but others, like uprooting all of your psychological obstacles, can be a real drag.  Don't stay in the land of the Fae to long.  Like any fairy story will tell you, you run the risk of getting trapped there forever.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello,**

I believe **they do exist but it's not the main point in Buddhism.** If you practice and feel devotion and do believe that Buddha is here even tho he entered paranirvana you will have faith that other beings may exist. Practice Yidam Yoga and talk with your Guru about this maybe he will help you figuring this out. You shouldn't have a blind faith about this but a faith that comes from understanding.

**Keep leaning Dharma and practicing for the benefit of all sentient beings. :)**

**Wish you well**